# JQuery POST to NODEJS (express)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, post

EDIT:
Project on Github: https://github.com/jackphumphrey/medisearch

I am very new to NODEjs so sorry if this is an easy/dumb question

I am attempting to send a POST request w/ JQuery ($.post) which is located: /public/javascripts/user.js

user.js in called in the  of index.html after jquery

index.html loads fine, however the $.post request sends an error

I think my main problem is that I don't know WHERE (as in location in node) I am suppose to send the post request

My directory:
mainfolder/

public/index.html &
public/javascripts/user.js

app.js &
routes/users.js, routes/index.js

user.js (located in public/)

```js
$.post('/users', JSON.stringify({username : 'data', useremail : 'data@data.com'}), function(response, status) {
        
}, "json")
    .done(function(response) {  
        alert(response);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('error: ' + error + ' status: ' + status);
    })
    .always(function(response) {
        console.log('^ RESPONSE: ' + response);
});
```

users.js (located in routes/)

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/users', function(req, res) {
  var userName = req.body.username;
  var userEmail = req.body.useremail;
  console.log('Username: ' + userName + ' Email: ' + userEmail);
  res.send('Username: ' + userName + ' Email: ' + userEmail);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am running it on digital ocean @ port 8080

Comment: In order to send json to server you also need to set appropriate Content-type header. At server end you also need to require a  bodyParser

Comment: In which file & where in that file would I include bodyParser? I posted the GitHub link so you can look at the full code, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jquery code below:

```
$("button").click(function(){
      $.post("/users",
      {
        name: "osasere",
        city: "stack"
      },
      function(data, status){
        console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
});
```

In your app.js file make sure to use:

```
const express = require('express')
const userRouter = require('./routes/users')
const app = express()

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(userRouter)
```

If it doesn't work, try to contact me.

Comment: I already have those. I posted the link to the GitHub project so you can take a look at the full code so see if anything is misplaced.